# Text Component Given Number of Lines in different Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I recently learned how to pass different styles based on component and was hoping the same rule applied for passing different props but I'm having a hard time with it.

So here I have a text component:

```
const TextTitle = ({ text }) => (
  <Text
    accessible={true}
    style={styles.songTitleText}
    numberOfLines={2}
    ellipsizeMode={'tail'}
  >
    {text}
  </Text>
);
```

but I want to use this text component elsewhere but instead, only give it `numberOfLines={1}`

So I tried

```
const SongTitle = ({ text, numberOfLines }) => (
  <Text
    accessible={true}
    style={styles.songTitleText}
    numberOfLines={[2, numberOfLines]}
    ellipsizeMode={'tail'}
  >
    {text}
  </Text>
);
```

and then in another component I call it with:

```
<TextTitle
 style={styles.itemText}
 text={Text_Word}
 numberOfLines={1}
 />
```

But I get an error in my simulator: `JSON Value '(2, 1)' of type NSMutableArray cannot be converted to NSNumber`

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this the same way you do with styles. I'm guessing you want to have the numbers of lines default to two, but when the user explicitly passes it, to use that value. If so, you can use the logical OR operator:

```
const TextTitle = ({ text, numberOfLines }) => (
  <Text
    …
    numberOfLines={numberOfLines || 2}
  >
    …
  </Text>
);
```

This checks to see if `numberOfLines` was passed to the component. If yes, then it's used, if not, the default of 2 is used. This is because the [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) operator evaluates to the left operand if it's truthy, and the right operand if it is falsey.

---

Note that there's also a more readable built-in way of accomplishing this with logical OR, assigning the [`defaultProps` static property](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values). Per the documentation:

> You can define default values for your props by assigning to the special defaultProps property

Thus:

```
const TextTitle = ({ text, numberOfLines }) => (
  <Text
    …
    numberOfLines={numberOfLines}
  >
    …
  </Text>
);

TextTitle.defaultProps = {
  numberOfLines: 2
};
```

This does the same thing as above, just more readable and "semantically correct" as React offers this for you as a built-in feature.

Comment: that was beautifully explained! Thank you @Li357